# Use time between locations instead of distance to optimize VRP

Tags: jsprit

I'm trying to use jsprit for my VRP problem. The problem is as follows:

1. I have multiple locations (services), and a matrix of transit times between them
2. I have a finite number of vehicles
3. I need to model a problem with jsprit such that it uses the transit times, instead of the coordinate distance between the locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the example](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/examples/AdditionalDistanceConstraintExample.java).

> matrixBuilder.addTransportTime(from, to, time);

Above code is used to add time. If you don't want to add distance constraints just remove

> matrixBuilder.addTransportDistance(from, to, distance);

Comment: Sutirtha thanks for that. I found that and got it working a couple of days after.

Comment: @sutirtha is it possible to optimize the problem by adding both distance matrix and time windows in a problem?

Comment: Yes. Those just two different constraints and can work together.